# Native function call from Actionscript3 using sockets

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, flex4

Is it possible to remotely call c++ native functions from actionscript3 flex 4 application? Can some suggest any sample code? I'm fine with writing a Adobe AIR app. I found a [blog](http://diogocabralphd.wordpress.com/tag/actionscript-3/) giving some ideas, but there was no code

Comment: "call c++ functions from actionscript" - lolwhat? ActionScript and C++ are different beasts with no interoperability. You should clarify what do you mean.

Comment: a lot of our code functionality is in c++ and i want to use as3 for user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Socket class to set up a TCP connection to a server that happens to be a compiled C++ executable, and could even be running on the same machine (localhost), that is a very typical use of the Socket class.

But the way your question is worded, it sounds like you want your swf to make function calls to a C++ compiled DLL or similar, which is not possible. Macromedia's Director product allowed this sort of thing with its wonderful Xtras native plug-in architecture (COM based), but the Flash Player has no equivalent**.

**EDIT: Turns out there is some equivalent functionality available for the AIR 2 runtime environment. I'm adding this for the sake of completeness, even though you did not specify that your app is an AIR app.

Check out this Adobe post: http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2010/03/extending_air_applications_with_plugins.html

and this:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html

also this example:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/air_screenrecording.html

Comment: the nativeprocess in Adobe AIR only allows communication via stdin/stdout/stderr. i'm happy to use a tcp connection to a c++ server from actionscript 3..is there any example for that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Alchemy : http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/

Comment: this would compile a c++ code base to as3 as a swf, but what I require is to make c++ calls from AS3 over a TCP socket(if any one has tried and knows if this is possible)

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to a TCP server in Flash with the [`Socket`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html) class.

The security requirements for serving policy files can be a bear if you're working in Flash Player rather than AIR.

These examples may help, though I can't guarantee they're up to date for security requirements:

- [Adobe example: socket policy server](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html)
- [Adobe example: Telnet client](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=17_Networking_and_communications_8.html)